# String replace using SED/AWK

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, sh

I want to replace a part of string in a file, i.e. replace `NFIN=4` to `W=4N`.
Please note that in the numeric part of `NFIN=4`, the number can be any int or float value; if the input was `NFIN=3.0`, the output should be `W=3.0`.
There are no negative number, its either 3 or 3.0. 
For example, the input line:

```
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N NFIN=4 ODIND=5
```

should become the output:

```
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N W=4N ODIND=5
```

Comment: If you don't mean that negative numbers with negative exponents are intended, then update the question appropriately.

Comment: sed -E -inplace 's/\bNFIN=([[:digit:]]+)\b/W=\1N/' PREICG_X1M_AH360TL_C8_ARCH_3_4.lpeSpc

Comment: It's significant because it makes the number-matching regex much more complex, but the basics are the same.  Can the NFIN entry ever appear at the beginning (unlikely) or end of the line? If it is always in the middle of a line, that too makes life easier. If the number is always valid (for example, there is never an entry like `NFIN=Aleph-Null` that should not be changed), then the fact that it is a number after `NFIN=` becomes largely immaterial. Playing with regexes is a fine art; you want something flexible enough to do what you want without doing too much or too little. Know your data!

Comment: What happens to `NFIN=NFIN`?

Comment: Nope NFIN=5N will appear only at 7th or 8th position of any particular line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed` command to match numerical data:

```
cat file
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N NFIN=4 ODIND=5
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N NFIN=FOO ODIND=5
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N NFIN=4.0 ODIND=5

sed -E 's/NFIN=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/W=\1/g; s/NFIN=([0-9]+)/W=\1N/g' file
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N W=4N ODIND=5
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N NFIN=FOO ODIND=5
XMPparasitic2 VDD:F86 VDD:F87 VDD:F88 VNW pch_lvt_mac L=8N W=4.0 ODIND=5
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed -E 's/NFIN=([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)/W=\1N/' file
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Poor questions shouldn't just be given poor answers; that helps nobody.